# Почему в анонимной функции не работает this?

Tags: javascript, функции

Почему в javascript в анонимной функции не работает this?

```
var counter = function (){
  this.count = 1;
}
 console.log(counter.count);
```

Прокомментируйте пожалуйста след. код javascript:

```
var foo = function (){
 console.log(foo.count + 1);
}
foo.count = 1;
foo();
```

Результат равен 2. Как это работает?

Comment: @z_coder а что вас удивляет?

Comment: То, что объект создается и при этом не работает this. При этом в функции foo() в лоб указывается объект foo.

Comment: объект не создается, создается closure
вас же не удивляет, то что 

    (function() {
       console.log(this);
    })();

использует `this` родительской области видимости ?

Comment: вот кажется придумал как объяснить

когда создается область видимости функции, то переменные не являющиеся аргументом функции, не объявленные с помошью var или function, считаются импортированными из родительскоф области видимости, this в том числе, другой вопрос, что объявлять this нельзя напрямую, можно вызвать функцию например так:

    var counter = function (){
      this.count = 1;
    }
    counter.apply(counter);

что сообщит функции, что её this в данном вызове объект counter;

Comment: Спасибо, с this кажись покончено. Только вот еще один вопрос:

Что это за объект такой, который ссылка на анонимную функцию?

Comment: объект функции, я там ниже писал его место в иерархии объектов

Answer (score 3):

Вот такая вот особенность JavaScript.  this указывает на глобальный объект window в случае, если функция не является методом какого-либо объекта. Ваш counter принадлежит глобальному объекту window, соответственно, в качестве this вы получаете window, у которого нет свойства count (его область видимости распространяется только на функцию). В случае, если функция вызывается как метод какого-либо объекта, this ссылается на этот объект, а в случае обращения к this из конструктора эта переменная будет ссылаться на создаваемый объект.

Из вышесказанного втекает нижеследующее - в общем-то предмет вашего вопроса является частным случаем того правила, что this cskftncz на тот объект, к которому относится функция, то есть window

Comment: короче говоря:

    var counter = function (){
      this.count = 1;
    }
    console.log(new counter().count);

Comment: function foo(){

}

var obj = new foo();

Здесь функция foo() не явлеяется методом какого-то объекта, однако this указывает на объект - результат new foo();
Как это понимать? Или вы были не точны?

Comment: @z_coder вы о чем ? вообще говоря, если function foo() объявлена в глобальной области видимости то она будет методом объекта window, но если область видимости неглобальна, то она будет методом скрытого объекта scope, но обычно про это можно думать как то что она не метод, а просто функция.